# Show/Hide DIVs based on DIV click

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I have following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery( document ).ready(function ($) {
        $('#telefon').click(function () {
            $('#telefon-text').show('fast');
            $('#sos-text').hide('fast');
            $('#positionsbestimmung-text').hide('fast');
        });
        $('#sos').click(function () {
            $('#telefon-text').hide('fast');
            $('#sos-text').show('fast');
            $('#positionsbestimmung-text').hide('fast');
        });
        $('#positionsbestimmung').click(function () {
            $('#telefon-text').hide('fast');
            $('#sos-text').hide('fast');
            $('#positionsbestimmung-text').show('fast');
        });
    });
</script>
```

and its working fine, the problem I have is that once i click for example first DIV and try to click on it again to close it it does not close. It only close when I click next one. What I need to change here to make it also close when I click on it second time?

Comment: use `.toggle("fast")` instead of `show/hide`

Comment: You can use jquery's `.toggle()`, but can not provide a working sample for your case if you do not post your html as well.

Comment: Do I add .toggle() for each of them or only one that I want to show?

Comment: @Boris, you can check my answer for a working demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery `.toggle()`:

Example:

```
   $('#sos').click(function () {
        $('#telefon-text').hide('fast');
        $('#sos-text').toggle('fast');
        $('#positionsbestimmung-text').hide('fast');
    });
```

Toggle basically takes care of some of the logic for you. Namely, if the element is hidden it shows it, if its shown it hides it.

Working example:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#btnFoo').click(function() {
    $('#foo').toggle("fast");
    $('#bar').hide("fast");
  });


  $('#btnBar').click(function() {
    $('#bar').toggle("fast");
    $('#foo').hide("fast");
  });

});
```

```css
.example {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: teal;
  border: dashed 2px pink;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example" id="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="example" id="bar">Bar</div>
<button id="btnFoo">Show/Hide Foo</button>
<button id="btnBar">Show/Hide Bar</button>
```

Comment: If I add .toggle() on all three as you suggested and click on any DIV it opens all three.

Comment: Edited - you want to hide the other two elements, only toggle the one you want open/close.

Comment: @wahwahwah, you said `Toggle basically takes care of some of the logic for you`, but he can take care of all his needs with toggle without any extra code, so he can keep his code clean as well.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested on the previous answer, you can do it with `.toggle()`, but you need to toggle only relative div to the clicked button, so:

```
$('#telefon').click(function () {
    $('#telefon-text').toggle('fast');
});
$('#sos').click(function () {
    $('#sos-text').toggle('fast');
});
$('#positionsbestimmung').click(function () {
    $('#positionsbestimmung-text').toggle('fast');
});
```

you can see working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/yxf4g93w/

Answer (score 0):

First, apply a class that is common to all your s.

```
<div class="div-class-here"></div>
<div class="div-class-here"></div>
<div class="div-class-here"></div>
```

Then,

```
var $divs = $( '.div-class-here' );

$divs.on( 'click', function () {
  $divs.removeClass( 'fast' );
  $( this ).addClass( 'fast' );
});
```